# Javascript not working on mobile view but working on desktop view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using that script two times on the same page one for desktop view and one for mobile view actually it's part of WordPress shortcode so I am using shortcode in two places.
But it is working fine on desktop view but not on mobile view.

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
        const BTN_BANNER_FORM = document.querySelector('#btn-banner-form');

        BTN_BANNER_FORM.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const BANNER_FORM = document.querySelector('#orderform');
            e.preventDefault();
            BANNER_FORM.submit();
        });

        const changeValue = () => {
            const totalPrice = document.getElementById("total_price");
            const form = document.querySelector('#orderform');
            const orderCostValue = document.getElementById("ordercost")?.value;
            totalPrice.textContent = orderCostValue || 0

            form?.addEventListener('change', () => {
                const value = document.getElementById("ordercost")?.value;
                totalPrice.textContent = value || 0
            });
        }

        console.log("Working");

        (function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:  'https://app.perfectessay.com/room.php?frontcalc=pc&typeofdocument=1&urgency=13',
                success: (data) => {
                    $('#price_calc_bl').html(data);
                    $('.pe_price_cal_right_side').addClass('active');
                    changeValue();
                },
            });
        }());
        changeValue();
    });

</script>
```